# How to evaluate memory footprint of redis key-value in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I want to store some users' info to redis for each user. Data type is used key-value.

For example:

```
$redis.set("user_info:12345", #{some data})
```

Is there any way to evaluate memory footprint?

I think redis key and value all will consume the memory, how to know how much memory consumed?

Comment: You want to get the size of a key's value, or memory info about the server?

Comment: I want t get the size of key's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the serialized length of a key's value with the `DEBUG OBJECT` command:

```
$redis.set("hello", "world")
$redis.debug("object", "hello")
# => "Value at:0x7f86f350a8d0 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:6 lru:2421685 lru_seconds_idle:13"
```

And if you want to extract that number, you can use this regex: `/serializedlength:(\d+)/`

```
size = $redis.debug("object", "hello").match(/serializedlength:(\d+)/)[1].to_i
# => 6
```

Comment: [serializedlength:6] means that six bytes?

Comment: @liuzxc It appears so, but documentation on that command is very sparse.

Comment: This command is disabled on Elasticache Redis. Hopefully there is another way.

Answer (score 2):

As of v4, we have the MEMORY USAGE command that does a much better job, reflecting the entire RAM consumption of key names, their values and all associated overheads of the internal data structures.

```
$redis.memory :usage, key_name
```

DEBUG OBJECT output is not a reliable way to measure the memory consumption of a key in Redis - the `serializedlength` field is given in bytes needed for persisting the object, not the actual footprint in memory that includes various administrative overheads on top of the data itself.

To illustrate this, I created a set of 2.5 million integers and compared the output of each:

```
> r.memory :usage, 'testkey'
=> 132003825

> r.debug :object, 'testkey'
=> "Value at:0x7fe739e09a00 refcount:1 encoding:hashtable serializedlength:12404474 lru:729393 lru_seconds_idle:68"
```

- `MEMORY USAGE` reports 132,003,825 bytes (126 MiB)
- `DEBUG OBJECT` reports only 12,404,474 bytes (12 MiB)

Answer (score 1):

if you need information on global used and available memory on the server, use `$redis.info(:memory)`